# Parametric Equation with a Parameter and an Angle

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

So, just now I was doing computing some parametric equations and graphing them when I came across a weird problem. I attempted to search for a solution, but I don't think I was able to describe what I meant well enough to get any useful results.

$x=t\cos(\theta) $ and $y = t \sin(\theta)$, $t>0$ over the interval $[0,\pi]$

I was able to eliminate the parameter to get $ y = x \tan(\theta)$. The problem I am having is what do I do with the $\theta$?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have a curve in polar form.  Yes you can convert it to Cartesian form, but it would really help to know how $t$ is defined.  Substitute $t = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in the definition of $t.$  With an arbitrary $t$ as it is, your curve could be just about anything.

Comment: Should I make a definition of $\theta$ relative to $t$ and graph that?

Comment: There may not be a nice expression in Cartesian form.  Easiest thing to do is take a ruler and a protractor and measure $t$ units out from your origin for each angle of $\theta.$  But, maybe some examples would help.  What is $t$?

Comment: That's the polar equation of a circle of radius $t$, where the tracing point is at an angle$\theta$. So if you keep $t$ constant you have a circle, if you keep $\theta$ constant you have a line ($y=tan(\theta) x$), if both are variable you have all the plane.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$\theta$ is a parameter.
We have equation 
$$x=0$$ 
when $\cos\theta=0$ and
$$y=x\tan\theta$$
when $\cos\theta\not=0.$